# How do you open a C# project in VB, using Visual Studio, so VB and C# programmers can both work on the same project?

Tags: c#, vb.net

It was a promise at the start of .NET, almost 20 years ago. We were supposed to be able to work on the same project as a team, not matter which language we used.

The initial attempt was so bad, due to functionality differences of languages, that most IT departments just focused on C and didn't hire VB programmers.

Surely things have improved since then. Is it possible yet to pull a C# file into VB and start working?

Comment: [You still can't.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278024/mixing-c-sharp-vb-in-the-same-project)

Comment: I have to done it by having 2 projects which one of them links in References the second.

Comment: This depends on the project type. you can mix VB and C# in ASP.net sites, but you can't in exe's or dlls. you can mix projects with different languages within a solution. That said, there really shouldn't be such a thing as a C# developer or a VB developer. there are only .Net developers. its trivial to convert VB to C# and back again.

Comment: My current project is an ASP project.

I have been looking for a good translator. I have tried a few free, online, translators. I don't know whether it is the limited number of lines you can enter, or the limitations of translators, but most of the time, all I see is the same exact characters in the same place on both before and after boxes. The same on both sides indicates to me that the translator didn't recognize the code so just cloned the lines.

Comment: Is there any chance you have that promise from 20 years ago documented anywhere?  I would sure like to read it.

Comment: I have been using .NET and used Visual Studio .NET(the version after Visual Studio 6) since before they were released.  I never recall a promise where you could open the same project and use Visual Basic .NET and C#.  Of course that's not entirely true.  You can create a single project and place multiple projects of different languages in it.  A project just can't be multiple languages.

Comment: Sure! I'll post the MS webpage that promoted it.

Oh, wait, it's 404'd.

Comment: The promise was, as I recall, that someone could be developing in C, and once sent to the compiler, the compiler could reverse engineer the code to VB so a VB programmer could work on it.